# How to add spaces in between charaters of a string

Tags: string, lua

```
string1 = "ASDFJKL" ----> string1 = "A S D F J K L"
```

I am using `string.match()` to find a specific letter in a string of random letters and this calls for the letters to be spaced out any way to do this

Or should I be using a different method of checking the string for my desired content?

Comment: To check if letter `D` is present somewhere in your string: `if string1:find("D") then ... end`

Answer (score 5):

Do it in just **one line**:

`string1 = string1:gsub(".", "%1 "):sub(1,-2)`

**Explain:**

1. `string1:gsub(".", "%1 ")` Find every character and add a space behind each character.
2. `:sub(1,-2)` Remove the last space character.

Comment: Or `string1:gsub("()"," "):sub(2,-2)`.  Or `string1:gsub("."," %0"):sub(2)`